# Open Youtube VideoWall Video in App

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I implemented a youtube video wall using the sample apllications: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

I want to open the youtube app when I am clicking on the video that is currently playing. How can I perform this? Is it also possible playing another video in the wall clicking on it?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The code below will open the youtube app.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
startActivity( launchIntent );
```